# DownloadFileAsync downloads a 0KB file

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, console-application

My code looks like this:

```
    private static WebClient wc = new WebClient;
...
wc.DownloadFileAsync(URL, FilePath);
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, ev) =>
{
    //Do stuff
};
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, ev) =>
{
    //All the rest of the code
};
```

However, as soon as DownloadFileAsync is executed, the program immediately closes leaving me with a 0KB file instead of the downloaded file (no error occurs).
I believe that it just completely ignores DownloadProgressChanged and executes the code inside the brackets. I'm just assuming

Comment: You need to show more code of where DownloadFileAsync is called. Your program is likely ending before the download completes. Because this is a console application most likely you just need to change it to a normal `DownloadFile` and move the code in `DownloadFileCompleted` after the download file call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Chamberlain correctly states, your program seemingly ends before `DownloadFileCompleted` gets called.  If this assumption is correct, wait in the main thread until then, like so:

```
var completed = new AutoResetEvent(false);
wc.DownloadFileAsync(URL, FilePath);
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, ev) =>
{
    //Do stuff
};
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, ev) =>
{
    //All the rest of the code
    completed.Set();
};
completed.WaitOne();
```